# Change route path in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a resource that I would like to change the path of.

```
resources :blog_posts
```

That makes the path `localhost:3000/blog_posts/:id`

How do I make it so it instead of having the "blog_posts" in front of it, the id comes right after, like this? `localhost:3000/:id`

I'm guessing there's a way to make this dynamic, so I don't have to do a `get` for every new blog post.

**ANSWER**

`get '/:id', to: 'blog_posts#show', as: :show_blog_post`

You need the `as: :show_blog_post` because the prefix won't be there. For example, you'll be able to call `show_blog_post_path(@blog_post)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define another route like: `get '/:id', to: 'blog_posts#show'`

Comment: Thanks @caspg. Got it to work. It didn't have a prefix, so I had to add to it. Question edited to include answer.